# Encrypted backup with Deja Dup fails on Ubuntu Budgie 17.10

Tags: encryption, gnupg, deja-dup

Can anyone help me with the following error? When trying to verify an encrypted backup with Deja Dup, it says the backup failed and it returns the following error:

```
GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: starting migration from earlier GnuPG versions
gpg: porting secret keys from '/home/username/.gnupg/secring.gpg' to gpg-agent
gpg: can't open '/home/userrname/.gnupg/secring.gpg': Permission denied
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

Comment: Assuming you edited this and put in 'username' (it's spelled 2 different ways) there is a permissions problem. Suggest you do a `ls -al` on the .gnupg directory and edit the results into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error when trying to restore my backup on 18.04. I've managed to find a workaround for my case which might also help for verification.
on the commandline run:

$ export PASSPHRASE= < your_passphrase >

(prepend it with a space to keep your password out of your command history
then instead of opening deja dup through a gui I open it through the same terminal,which in my case is:

$deja-dup --restore-missing ~